# SVN: Finding out merge source

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In SVN, after executing a merge command from a SOURCE to TARGET via TortoiseSvn for example.
I'd like to know if there's an svn command in cmd or python that can identify which branch exactly was selected as the source branch for that merge.
When I check the svn:mergeinfo for the TARGET, I find that SOURCE as well as other branches have changed in terms of merged revisions.
In short, what svn command can output the SOURCE merged branch to the working copy?

I'm talking about uncommitted changes on the working copy after executing a merge command. The reason behind this is that I wanna check the source and target inside the pre-commit hook script and block merges from certain branches to others. Imagine this scenario:

1-You check out branchA

2-You merge branchB(source) onto branchA.

3-Right before committing the merge commit, I'd like a command that could specify that branchB was merged locally.

Comment: Are you talking about a working copy with uncommitted changes or about finding out about merges that were already committed earlier? Could you explain what you mean with your statement that SOURCE and other branches have changed? How and in what way? Do you need the branch or the branch at a specific revision? Are you looking for a textual version of TortoiseSVN's revision graph?

Comment: Hi Friedrich, I'm talking about uncommitted changes on the working copy after executing a merge command. 
The reason behind this is that I wanna check the source and target inside the pre-commit hook script and block merges from certain branches to others. 
Imagine this scenario:
You check out branchA
You merge branchB(source) onto branchA.
Right before committing the merge commit, I'd like a command that could specify that branchB was merged locally.

Comment: Maybe your question would be clearer if you explained the problem you want to solve instead of your ideas how to solve it. Do you want to prevent people from committing changes that were merged from one specific branch to another one?

Comment: Well, I was just thinking out loud. Yes, I want to enforce a merge strategy.